# Will modified gravity helps find new technologies or improve existing technologies in our life on Earth?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, quantum-gravity, modified-gravity

If we were able to find a modified theory of gravity or a theory that better explains gravity than general relativity and fixes the problems of general relativity in places were general relativity fails, for example near center of black hole, will this theory improve current technologies such as GPS and other technologies that depend on general relativity?

Comment: Well, GPS seems to be working just fine running on GR!

Answer (score 4):

Any technology we are using today that depends on some physical theory will (at first) be unchanged by discovering a better theory. The fact that it already works proves enough for an engineer - Swiss watchmakers did not have to redo all clocks because Einstein supplanted Newtonian mechanics and reformulated time.

The second stage is when various anomalies now can be explained and modelled using the better theory. There might be "noise" and other problem behaviours in GPS that are actually due to things the new theory explains, and can now be handled much better.

The final stage is when the new properties of the new theory become useful for engineering. This may take a while - since almost by definition the effect size of the new theory is small in the already well-used technical arena any new technology will have to deal with higher precision, smaller forces or entirely new effects. There might also be entirely new technical arenas enabled by the theory. But one cannot make good predictions about this since it requires understanding a theory one does not have yet; if we could say much about it we would already know the theory.

Most likely GPS will keep on using GR since it is proven to work well enough. Maybe a post-GR theory enables GPS with far finer resolution, but whether that becomes common depends on not just science and engineering but also economics. It is likely that the big application is something we cannot foresee. The founders of quantum mechanics did not expect that the biggest use of their theory would be electronic computers.